# Mimick photoshop/painter smooth draw on HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

As many people knew, HTML5 Canvas `lineTo()` is going to give you a very jaggy line at each corner. At this point, a more preferable solution would be to implement `quadraticCurveTo()`, which is a very great way to generate smooth drawing. However, I desire to create a smooth, yet accurate, draw on canvas HTML5. Quadratic curve approach works well in smoothing out the draw, but it does not go through all the sample points. In other word, when I try to draw a quick curve using quadratic curve, sometime the curve appears to be "corrected" by the application. Instead of following my drawing path, some of the segment is curved out of its original path to follow a quadratic curve.

My application is intended for a professional drawing on HTML5 canvas, so it is very crucial for the drawing to be both smooth and precise. I am not sure if I am asking for the impossible by trying to put HTML5 canvas on the same level as photoshop or any other painter applications (SAI, painterX, etc.)

Thanks

Comment: Not entirely clear at what you are attempting. Are you tracing a curve with the mouse and expecting canvas to draw the exact curve the mouse has tracked?

Comment: mmm, +1: very interesting. However, if you're planning to do a professional drawing application, IMHO, you'd better go for a native application. The only advantage of a browser app is cross-compatibility but this has a huge price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a [Cardinal spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Cardinal_spline) as cardinal splines goes through the actual points you draw.

Note: to get a professional result you will also need to implement moving average for short thresholds while using cardinal splines for larger thresholds and using knee values to break the lines at sharp corner so you don't smooth the entire line. I won't be addressing the moving average or knee here (nor taper) as these are outside the scope, but show a way to use cardinal spline.

A side note as well - the effect that the app seem to modify the line is in-avoidable as the smoothing happens post. There exists algorithms that smooth while you draw but they do not preserve knee values and the lines seem to "wobble" while you draw. It's a matter of preference I guess.

Here is an fiddle to demonstrate the following:
<kbd>**[ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/4eLpe/)**</kbd>

First some prerequisites (I am using my [easyCanvas](http://easyCanvasJS.com/) library to setup the environment in the demo as it saves me a lot of work, but this is not a requirement for this solution to work):

- I recommend you to draw the new stroke to a separate canvas that is on top of the main one.
- When stroke is finished (mouse up) pass it through the smoother and store it in the stroke stack.
- Then draw the smoothed line to the main.

When you have the points in an array order by X / Y (ie `[x1, y1, x2, y2, ... xn, yn]`) then you can use this function to smooth it:

The *tension* value (`ts`, default 0.5) is what smooths the curve. The higher number the more round the curve becomes. You can go outside the normal interval [0, 1] to make curls.

The *segment* (`nos`, or number-of-segments) is the resolution between each point. In most cases you will probably not need higher than 9-10. But on slower computers or where you draw fast higher values is needed.

The function (optimized):

```
/// cardinal spline by Ken Fyrstenberg, CC-attribute
function smoothCurve(pts, ts, nos) {

    // use input value if provided, or use a default value   
    ts = (typeof ts === 'undefined') ? 0.5 : ts;
    nos = (typeof nos === 'undefined') ? 16 : nos;

    var _pts = [], res = [],        // clone array
        x, y,                       // our x,y coords
        t1x, t2x, t1y, t2y,         // tension vectors
        c1, c2, c3, c4,             // cardinal points
        st, st2, st3, st23, st32,   // steps
        t, i, r = 0,
        len = pts.length,
        pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4;

    _pts.push(pts[0]); //copy 1. point and insert at beginning
    _pts.push(pts[1]);

    _pts = _pts.concat(pts);

    _pts.push(pts[len - 2]);    //copy last point and append
    _pts.push(pts[len - 1]);

    for (i = 2; i < len; i+=2) {

        pt1 = _pts[i];
        pt2 = _pts[i+1];
        pt3 = _pts[i+2];
        pt4 = _pts[i+3];

        t1x = (pt3 - _pts[i-2]) * ts;
        t2x = (_pts[i+4] - pt1) * ts;

        t1y = (pt4 - _pts[i-1]) * ts;
        t2y = (_pts[i+5] - pt2) * ts;

        for (t = 0; t <= nos; t++) {

            // pre-calc steps
            st = t / nos;
            st2 = st * st;
            st3 = st2 * st;
            st23 = st3 * 2;
            st32 = st2 * 3;

            // calc cardinals
            c1 = st23 - st32 + 1; 
            c2 = st32 - st23;
            c3 = st3 - 2 * st2 + st; 
            c4 = st3 - st2;

            res.push(c1 * pt1 + c2 * pt3 + c3 * t1x + c4 * t2x);
            res.push(c1 * pt2 + c2 * pt4 + c3 * t1y + c4 * t2y);

        } //for t
    } //for i

    return res;
}
```

Then simply call it from the `mouseup` event after the points has been stored:

```
stroke = smoothCurve(stroke, 0.5, 16);
strokes.push(stroke);
```

Short comments on knee values:

A knee value in this context is where the angle between points (as part of a line segment) in the line is greater than a certain threshold (typically between 45 - 60 degrees). When a knee occur the lines is broken into a new line so that only the line consisting of points with a lesser angle than threshold between them are used (you see the small curls in the demo as a result of not using knees).

Short comment on moving average:

[Moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) is typically used for statistical purposes, but is very useful for drawing applications as well. When you have a cluster of many points with a short distance between them splines doesn't work very well. So here you can use MA to smooth the points.

There is also point reduction algorithms that can be used such as the [Ramer/Douglas/Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) one, but it has more use for storage purposes to reduce amount of data.

Comment: The demo is down due to the canvas lib you build going missing - I'm very, very interested to see an example of moving average to smooth the mouse noise in real-time - Is that something that you have as a demo?